# jQuery add timeout to random text array

Tags: jquery, timeout

I have a link that changes text every time its clicked but I am trying to find a way for it to automatically switch to the next variable after a period of time, sort of like a rotator.

This is what I have:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
    var quotes = [
        'Link 1',
        'Link 2',
        'Link 3',
        'Link 4',
        'Link 5',
        'Link 6'
    ];

    function loadQuote(i) {
        return quotes[i];
    }

    function randNumber() {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * quotes.length );
    }
    $('#button-reload').click(function() {
            $(this).html(loadQuote(randNumber()));
    });
    $('#button-reload').html(loadQuote(randNumber()));
});​
```

and here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMv7v/)

any ideas?

Comment: +1 for good question formatting.

Comment: Lots of practice haha ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var quotes = [
        'Link 1',
        'Link 2',
        'Link 3',
        'Link 4',
        'Link 5',
        'Link 6'
    ];

    var $theLink = $('#button-reload');

    function loadQuote(i) {
        return quotes[i];
    }

    function randNumber() {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * quotes.length );
    }

    function changeTheQuote() {
        $theLink.html(loadQuote(randNumber())); 
    }

    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        changeTheQuote();
    }, 3000); 

    $theLink.click(function() {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        changeTheQuote();
        interval = window.setInterval(function(){
            changeTheQuote();
        }, 3000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited version of Habibillah's answer

Comment: it seems to take a second to show up when the page first loads, is this because of the delay?

Comment: @JB. Yeah, its because of how it was structured originally. You never set the contents of the link directly, you only did it with the swap function. You could just set an initial value in the HTML `<a href="#" id="button-reload">Link 1</a>`, or you can add a call to `changeTheQuote();` immediately before the closing `});`

Answer (score 3):

Try use [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) like code bellow:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var quotes = [
        'Link 1',
        'Link 2',
        'Link 3',
        'Link 4',
        'Link 5',
        'Link 6'
    ];

    function loadQuote(i) {
        return quotes[i];
    }

    function randNumber() {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * quotes.length );
    }

    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        $('#button-reload').html(loadQuote(randNumber()));            
    }, 3000);   

    $('#button-reload').click(function() {
        $(this).html(loadQuote(randNumber()));

        //uncomment line bellow to stop intarval when button clicked.
        //window.clearInterval(interval);
    });  
});
```

Comment: I would put the code into a function so it can be called as soon as the page is loaded and also in the interval...

Comment: I agree with elclanrs, also I would add `window.clearInterval(interval)` to the click handler and then restart the interval after reloading the quote. This avoids the quote from switching immediately after manually switching it.

Comment: elclanrs, I put inline code inside window.interval because it just one line. It's clear to me to separate the code into a function and then called by window.interval. @JamesSwift, I move my commented code into .click() event.

Comment: @JB. I posted the edited code as an answer, dont vote it up, it is just an edit of Habibillah